# VSFTPD – How to fix this security issue?

Tags: ssh, permissions, users, vsftpd

I've created a user called `example` using `adduser` command and setted its password and everything. That was part of the VSFTPD setup process.

However, I've noticed that I can also access using the port 22 both in my VPS' SSH console and SFTP / FTP. How can I make it so that it is only FTP accessible ?

I'm gonna share my server with a client to let him create a static HTML site using only and no more than FTP.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable ssh access for a particular user you could set  its SSH shell to /bin/false.

Comment: and probably `chroot` them into a jail.  The openssh server can do this with its internal sftp subsystsem.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sftp in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Some would argue that using FTP is more of a security issue that sftp.

Comment: I don't want to disable the SFTP service completely, I use SFTP for my root user, but I would like to disable the SFTP and SSH services for my `example` user.

Comment: VSFTPD virtual users are probably your way forward.